# Call dotnet asmx webservice with parameter using android volley library in android

Tags: android, web-services, asmx, android-volley

I am facing an issue calling .net .asmx web service with parameter using android volley library.

Without parameter its working fine.

This my web service

```
[WebMethod]
private string MN_InsEOMTestScoreDetailsIndividual(string data)
{
    ArrayList arrReturnDetails = new ArrayList();
    bool bReturn = false;
    string errMsg = globalErrMsg;
    try
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dicData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(data);

        bReturn = InsEOMTestScoreDetailsIndividual(dicData["eomTSIndvlDetId"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["eomTRDetId"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["eomTSSummDetId"].ToString().Trim(),
        dicData["studCode"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["ctrCode"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["batCode"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["phCode"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["pcCode"].ToString().Trim(),
        dicData["tmCode"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["testActualDur"].ToString().Trim(),
             dicData["testAttemptDur"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["testTtlMks"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["mksObt"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["ttlQues"].ToString().Trim(),
             dicData["rAnsCnt"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["wAnsCnt"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["attemptTestDate"].ToString().Trim(),
             dicData["isSolViewed"].ToString().Trim(), dicData["quesXML"].ToString().Trim(), out errMsg);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandler.LogError("WebService:APP_UserActivityDetails", "M_InsEOMTestScoreDetailsIndividual", ex);
    }
    arrReturnDetails.Add(new
    {
        b = bReturn,
        err = errMsg
    });
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrReturnDetails);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your web service is probably a **GET** web service which you are trying to invoke as **POST**. That won't work. There are two ways to correct this:

- Make sure your web service is of **POST** type and then add your parameters as a `HashMap` in the Volley request.
- If you want to keep the web service as a **GET**, then append the parameters manually to the URL string (i.e. don't pass them as key-value pairs in a `HashMap`).

Comment: my added my webservice in question..and its already in POST method

Comment: Ya but unable to parse the json object